# WordPress notification reports

Tags: wp-admin, notices, wp-error

I had to make a standalone dashboard for WordPress.

I designed an interface to notify users of information messages (eg wrong user password) such as verification of forms and files or errors.

But I have to carry messages just like **wordpress**. It is carrying messages in the WordPress admin panel with I guess (`transients`).

**(1) Is this true or did I get it wrong?**

> NOTE: As far as I know WooCommerce also uses a similar method while giving an error message on the frontend.

**(2)** What kind of function should I develop if I want to move the messages created by a method like (transients) and press the screen? So what should my road map be like?

**For example:** Should I follow a way like catching an event (in Javascript language)?

```
addEventListener -> in event -> removeEventListener
setTransient -> when run getTransient -> deleteTransient
```

---

Or should I do the same with PHP session? Which one do you think is healthy?